# Install CAS Server on Tomcat Fail

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, cas

I'm trying to install CAS on tomcat 7.
but when I started the server, this error occured.

```
SEVERE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/casLoginView.jsp (line: 49, column: 33) Attribute value request.getQueryString() == null ? "" : request.getQueryString().replaceAll("&locale=[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]|^locale=[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]", "") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a new system variable

```
JAVA_OPTS = "-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false"
```

it works like magic.